# WCF Rest do not accept xml declaration in request

Tags: c#, wcf

I am developing a WCF REST service to receive input from a third party company. It works fine if I send a plain xml-structure, but fails if the xml declaration is present in the request. Unfortunately I have no control over what is being sent, so I have to make this work WITH the declaration.

My service interface and implementation looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "report")]
    ResponseData Report(testclass req);
}

public class Service : IService1
{
    public string Report(testclass req)
    {
        return req.operatorStatusMessage;
    }
}
```

This is my testclass:

```
  [DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "testclass")]
    public partial class testclass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public ushort id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public byte statusCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string statusMessage { get; set; }

        public testclass()
        { }
    }
```

..and this is my Web.config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="SMSRep.Service" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SMSRep.IService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

The xml I am trying to send is this

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF8" ?>
<testclass>
   <id>6789</id>
   <statusCode>200</statusCode>
   <statusMessage>Some message</statusMessage>
 </testclass>
```

As I mentioned, without the xml declaration it works fine, 
if included I get an error '400 Bad Request'. The InnerException of the WebException says 'Protocol error'.

My testapp for sending looks like this:

```
const string url = "http://localhost:4337/Service.svc/Report";

    string txt = File.ReadAllText(xmlfile);
    byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt);

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    req.Timeout = 10000;
    req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;

    using (Stream streamWriter = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        streamWriter.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        txtReceive.Text = result;
    }
```

Have been Googling for days, please give me a hint someone!

Comment: You can intercept messages and manipulate them before allowing the [WCF pipeline](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stdeepdive/2012/05/07/wcf-extension-points-and-how-to-use-them/) to continue. However, this is not trivial. But why can't you dictate that the xml not have the declaration? Consumers of API's must conform to the request format, that's just how it works.

Comment: Not likely, the company is an SMS sending service and already supports several thousand customers. The service in question is for receiving delivery reports for SMS's being sent.

Comment: Well then you can implement a MessageInstpector to manipulate the xml before the OperationInvoker receives it. But do you even need a soap service? Can you just build a much simpler web api that receives `text/xml`?

Answer (score 0):

The xml file should have the schema instance. Try adding like this

```
<testclass xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
 <id>6789</id>
 <statusCode>200</statusCode>
 <statusMessage>Some message</statusMessage>
</testclass>
```

Note: Remove the root xml node.

If this also fails. Try doing a data contract serialization of the **contract in service** using [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=net-5.0) and then check if the xml string matches with what you have given in your request.